# Discussion around potential reasons for going over Postgres `work_mem`

Tags: database, postgresql, performance

Curious to get some discussion / opinion on a particular performance problem I'm having in Postgres. Greatly appreciate anyone who chimes in!

The essence / nature of the problem and some questions:

- I have a long running pipeline in which data flows into the database via many single upserts inside of a single transaction that gets committed once at the end of the pipeline. Each of these upserts seem to be causing us to go over `work_mem` and are consequently writing to disk. (Individual upserts can be seen going over in the logs)
- There are two unique indexes on the table we're upserting against: one of which is required for the pipeline to run and one which isn't. Could dropping the non required index before the pipeline and rebuilding it after help alleviate some pressure on our work_mem, and if so, why?
- Due to some nuance around how I'm receiving the data, the pipeline running in one transaction felt like a requirement at the time I engineered all of this. Could it be possible that running all of these upserts in a single transaction is contributing to the problem, and if so, why?
- For context, the underlying SQL for each of these upserts looks something like below. Is there some nuance around how these are done in CTEs and then selected from that could be contributing to the problem?
- We can assume each of these individual upserts contains a `MASSIVE_JSON_PAYLOAD` that is smaller than the current `work_mem` value.

```sql
WITH
    cte__some_table_inserted_rowsets AS (
        INSERT INTO
            "some_table" (...SOME_FIELDS, BIG_JSONB_ARRAY_FIELD)
        VALUES
            (
              ...SOME_FIELDS
              ...BIG_JSON_PAYLOAD
            )
        ON CONFLICT ("some_field", "some_field_2", "some_field_3") 
        DO UPDATE SET
        ...APPEND BIG_JSON_PAYLOAD TO EXISTING BIG_JSONB_ARRAY_FIELD
        RETURNING *
    )
SELECT * FROM cte__some_table_inserted_rowsets;
```

The logs that get reported look like something along the lines of:

`sql_error_code = 00000 LOG:  temporary file: path "...", size n`
`sql_error_code = 00000 STATEMENT:  ...THE_UPSERT`

The flag responsible for enabling / tweaking these kinds of logs: `log_temp_files`

This is all being done in PG10, and as far as how big `size n` is comparatively:

- `work_mem` is currently set to 32mb.
- The payload being processed by a single one of these upserts will never be more than a few mb.
- It’s very common to see one of these logs for a single upsert having a `size n` of 50+mb

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL is this?  Each of your INSERTS is of a single row , correct?

Comment: How does the value 'size n' in the log messages compare to the size of the payload?  To the size of work_mem?

Comment: @jjanes All of this is being done in PG10, and yes - each of these upserts is a single row. I've added some comparisons between the sizes of those things to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Can we see `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for one of the statements that write temp files?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  For me, the temp files are logged only if the payload is larger than about work_mem.  It is created when the CTE materializes its RETURNING tuple.  But I used ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, not knowing what else to do for it.  I also don't have indexes or constraints (other than the PK) or FKs or triggers.  Also, I doubt there is a problem here.  Work_mem has never been very rigid, and generating some temp files that are small enough not to ever get pushed out of the page cache is probably not very onerous.

Comment: JSON has its place, but it is basically a violation of NF1 Use it with caution.

Comment: @jjanes Ya, something I'll be trying soon-ish is running the pipeline in such a way that these upserts aren't done in a CTE / returned in any way

What sparked my curiosity around this was getting an email from the DB hosting provider mentioning that we're running out of temp space. I'm thinking it's just due to the fact that things being written to temp space aren't getting cleared out until the end of this long running transaction.